# How can a client search for server IP and port on same network using port scanning and IP scanning?

Tags: http, networking, port, ip-address, port-scanning

I am making an application which will start a HTTP server on a hard-coded port (assume the port is 32654)

There can be multiple clients on the same network which will try to search for this HTTP server. Since they don't know the server IP address, they will need to parallelly scan on each IP address from `xxx.xxx.xxx.1` to `xxx.xxx.xxx.254` at port 32654. (assume the subnet mask is 255.255.255.0)

Question-1) If the server finds that 32654 port is already taken by another application, it will need to start on other port. How should I re-design my IP address & port scanning logic in my client to efficiently search the new server port and IP address..

Question-2) If it is a large network and the subnet mask for the network is 255.255.0.0, is there an efficient way to search the correct IP address across this vast new search space?

Comment: That is not a good idea. You can have the server subscribe to a multicast group, then the clients can send a request to the multicast group, and the server can respond with its specifics that the clients can use for the HTTP connection.

Comment: Remember that scanning on networks is often considered suspicious behavior, and the offenders will be disconnected.